# What man or crew sized weapons should my infantry bring into an area where electricity doesn't work to help breakup trench warfare?

Tags: technology, warfare, firearms, guns

I have an area with highly valuable resources that is highly contested over. The only issue is that the moment someone enters the area, all electronics regardless of type stop working. As such only infantry is capable of operating in these areas.

Because this area/region is massive with uneven terrain, infantry is going to be doing a lot of work. Especially in regard to holding their side of the region. Naturally both sides start digging in and forming trenches. And eventually attacks against enemy trenches and fortifications begin.

**What man or crew sized weapons should my infantry bring into these regions to help breakup trench warfare where electronics don't work?**

**Notes:**

1. Vehicles or artillery firing from outside the region are possible, but they are not in the scope of the question, nor are they guaranteed to have range based on the vast distanced covered.
2. Production capabilities match present time; however, technology can scale to near future.
3. Trenches are long and manned in ways that are reminiscent of WW1 or current Russian invasion of Ukraine.
4. Steam locomotives are used for logistics inside the region where electricity doesn't work.
5. Gas, chemical, and biological warfare are not allowed.
6. The adversary is a peer opponent.

Comment: *"All electronics regardless of type stop working; as such only infantry is capable of operating":* Not really. WW1 and WW2 era automobiles, armored fighting vehicles and aircraft operated just fine without any electronics whatsoever. (And you may want to clarify whether is it *electronics* which does not work, as in the first paragraph, or *electricity* in general, as in the title; and in the latter case, how come that the hearts of the infrantrymen keep working.)

Comment: This seems to be a question about choices made by individuals in your world. Such questions are not appropriate for this site.

Comment: The old Chevy Blazer worked ok without electronics.  You would need to do a push start if the battery was dead.  The headlights would not turn on and also no AC but this is war so people can get sweaty.   They could bring the Blazer to the war.  It was pretty decent in uneven terrain.  Maybe put chains on.   And also bring some of those guns that dont need a battery.

Comment: @AlexP Fixed it to just electronics.

Comment: Is this basically a question about how to break an WWI-style infantry stalemate using WWI-style infantry tools? Generals (and and armchair generals) have tried to solve that problem for generations. There are several demonstrated solutions, but none are pretty or easy. Most require some form rapid, reliable, secure communication, a combined-arms organizational structure, and a plentiful supply of ammunition -- far more than individuals can readily carry.

Comment: @user535733 In a way yes and no. While yes, I am using an infantry focus in these regions, the soldiers have access to construct modern weapons so that is going to change how soldiers arm and equip themselves. There is access to more man portable weapons system at present than back from both WW1 or WW2. Logistics and ammunition can be brought in via rail and as someone mentioned below diesel engines. Solutions don't have to be pretty or a perfect solution. Just something to help aid things to.

Comment: The question specifies "*man or crew sized weapons*", which precludes the use of operational-level changes that have been the real historical solution(s). Too bad. Increases in the lethality of infantry-portable direct-fire weapons tend to make infantry stalemates *harder* to break -- that additional firepower tends to favor the defender.

Comment: You say "naturally", but extended front-long trenchworks are pretty much exclusively a feature of war dominated by artillery.

Comment: There are weaknesses here. What stops (e.g.) a nuclear ICBM from solving the problem? The ballistic path takes it above the affected area and the warheads drop via gravity - which is how they work in the first place. Why not use mortars, which don't rely on electricity at all? Why not use RPGs, which also don't require electricity? Humanity hasn't relied on electricity to fight a war until WWII at the earliest. It may not have relied on it until the 1970s. (There's a difference between "used it" and "relied on it.")

Answer (score 5):

One obvious answer, breaking your frame, is to construct tanks using diesel engines without a spark plug. These engines will be somewhat crude, but in this situation tanks might be a game changer.

Staying within your frame, one way to break trenches in WWI were [stormtrooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormtroopers_(Imperial_Germany)) tactics. Teams of infantry with SMGs and hand grenades, engineers with demolitions and flamethrowers, and light (for the time) machine guns integrated at a low level. Compare also WWII USMC tactics to defeat Japanese island fortifications, involving similar teams plus bazookas and tanks.

Translated into modern terms, troops with assault rifles, plenty of hand grenades, underbarrel grenade launchers, SAWs/LMGs, and RPGs/rockets to blast strongpoints, and demolitions. Which is not too far from the prescription for urban combat (minus air and ground vehicles).

Comment: Mike Mulligan can bring his coal fired steam shovel.   Maryanne will dig those trenches just fine. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Mulligan_and_His_Steam_Shovel

Answer (score 1):

## Nuclear bombs

Nuclear bombs have more destructive potential than any normal weapon a human could use, and can be [suit case sized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suitcase_nuclear_device) and [crew sized weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davy_Crockett_(nuclear_device)). While like many modern weapons they are designed to work with electricity, they don't need to do so. They're basically just rings of carefully timed explosives around nuclear material.

These can clear out troops, defenses, and heavy weapons positions.

Comment: That *"ring of carefully timed explosives"* is electronically timed. But a plain old gun-type bomb could indeed work with no electronics.

Comment: I agree with AlexP that one must rig the nuclear bomb with a fuse.  If I am involved please make it a long fuse because we will be riding bikes to make our escapes after we light the fuse.